# issue when sending null parameter to webapi

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I use angular.js and WebApi. I have a problem when sending null parameter to webapi. My code is like below:

```
 $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "http://xxxx",
        params: { id: null, uid: 123  }
    })
```

I use above code for seding to webapi side.

```
  public Product[] GetProductList([FromUri]int? id=null, [FromUri] int? uid=null)
  {
  }
```

My webapi code is like above. I get an error like "No action was found on the controller". If I give a value to "id" parameter, it works ok. I don not know where I am wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `JSON.stringify({ id: null, uid: 123  })`

Comment: This is a routing issue. Please add your routes in your question.